# How to assign a value by month for timeseries data?

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series data to which I am trying to assign a value based on which month the sample falls in. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

| Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 29-12-2018 | 1 |
| 31-12-2018 | 1 |
| 01-01-2019 | 2 |
| 05-01-2019 | 2 |
| 02-02-2018 | 3 |

I think I should be using groupby(), but I was not sure how to do that for a timeseries. Anyone know how use `timestamp` feature here to derive the `value` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the `Timestamp` from datetime to period and then grouping them helped me assign the values. Below is the required code for above dataframe:

```
df["Period"] = df['Timestamp'].dt.to_period('M')
df["Value"] = df.groupby(["Period"]).ngroup() + 1
```

So, I created a new col `Period` and then used groupby(), ngroup() methods on it to group and assign a unique value to each period and store in `Value` column.

| Timestamp | Period | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29-12-2018 | 12-2018 | 1 |
| 31-12-2018 | 12-2018 | 1 |
| 01-01-2019 | 01-2019 | 2 |
| 05-01-2019 | 01-2019 | 2 |
| 02-02-2018 | 02-2019 | 3 |

P.s I added 1 while creating `Value` as the groups were being assigned from 0 but I wanted the groups to start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime
timestamps = [datetime.datetime(1984, 1, 2)]

# format - month: value
valuesdict = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}

values = [valuesdict[i.month] for i in timestamps]
print(values)
```

This should work for your use case. The timestamps must be of type `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: The above code would be assigning a value based on the month which would limit my `value` feature to max val 12. But what I am looking for is to keep assigning values beyond 12. For the table in my question it would be assigning 12,12,1,1,2 (I did not run your code but that's what it looks like). Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @harthik Pretty sure values more than 12 can be assigned, change the value of the key in the dict.

Comment: I don't think adding keys to dict is the problem but the for loop where we get month from `timestamp` and map it to `valuesdict`. Example, if a sample is 29-01-2001 the value is 1 and for the next sample which maybe 29-01-2002 the value would be still 1 where I was expecting to have 13 instead. Correct me if I got that wrong.

Comment: Well, in your question you only mention about mapping the values based on month. So iIassumed each month to have one value.